# FileInputStream how to read a html file without replace html's icon

Tags: java, html

I hava a picture file and html file in my local disk, and every time a want to use local host to open html file, the picture in html will aotu replace with the picture which in my local disk. What is the reasion? thx

```
String parts[] = request.split(" ");
        if(parts.length==3){
            if(parts[0].compareTo("GET")==0){
                String filename = parts[1].substring(1);
                System.out.println(filename);
                if(filename.compareTo("")==0){
                    FileInputStream defult = new FileInputStream("C:\\google.html");
                    byte byteArray[] = new byte[defult.available()];
                    while((b = defult.read(byteArray)) != -1){
                        //println(stream,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                        //println(stream,"");
                        stream.write(byteArray);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:\\picture.jpg");
                    byte byteArray[] = new byte[input.available()];
                    while((b = input.read(byteArray)) != -1){
                        //println(stream,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                        //println(stream,"");
                        sleep(1000);
                        stream.write(byteArray);
                        }
                 }
```

in the code `b` is a int variable,`stream` is FileInputStream, and `println` is a function with bufferedOutPutStream. And `request` will get something like that "GET / HTTP/1.1"
For example, when I type http://localhost:8080/ into location bar, the google search icon will be replaced[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02BKg.png)

Comment: Just a guess - because you have hard-coded a path into your code?

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking at all here. What is the scenario, what is it that you want to do?

Also, this is 2016, so please don't use `FileInputStream`; use `Files.newInputStream` instead.

Comment: I'm a uni student, and be asked to use FileInputStream... The thing I want to do is "return a default page when no le is specied in the location bar. For example, http://localhost:8080/ could return google.html"

Comment: Does your HTML contain a relative link or an absolute link to the picture?

Comment: The HTML file should not contain any relative link, as I got it by go to Google search and right click "save as".

Answer (score 0):

The problem that document have to have relative paths instead of absolute. As you say you just click `Save to...`. Some browsers handling that action do some more than just save page source code, they download all dependencies and update all paths in your document to absolute links to you hard drive. So this is not what you want. Try to save page code by opening it source code and just copying it to you google.html instead of `Save to..` action.

Comment: Are there any possible to fix it?

Comment: I was wrong.. Just rewrite my answer. Try to follow it :)